# Event of dynamically created Control not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a problem with a Web Control that is dynamically created and inserted in my page. I create a couple of LinkButtons, depending on the data of the search that was made, and I'm trying to add an Event Handler to each of the Buttons, so it would filter the result.

The controls are initialized properly, but the event is never fired.

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
  Controls.Clear()

  Dim btn As Controls.LocalizableLinkButton
  For Each element As Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, ResultFilterData) In m_list

    btn = New LocalizableLinkButton
    btn.ID = m_Name & "$lnk" & count
    btn.Label = element.Value.Label.Append(" (" + CStr(element.Value.Count) + ")")
    btn.CommandArgument = element.Value.Key
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.btn_Click

    Controls.Add(btn)
  Next
End Sub
```

Since this code is in Page_Init all the controls should be recreated on a postback. (The LocalizableLinkButton is just an extension of a LinkButton to add multilingual features to the text).

The problem is that the method btn_Click is never called. The Link Buttons are properly initialized on the callback, with the same ID's as before. But the event doesn't fire.

I'm using ASP.Net 2.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you set the page's or UserControl's [ClientIDMode](http://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair) to "Static"`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using ASP.Net 2.0, and ClientIDMode was only introduced in 4.0, so that won't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem ASP.NET had with my Link Buttons.

The error was in using a '$' sign in my ID for each LinkButton. ASP.NET apparently uses the $ sign to build the control hierarchy when it creates the Postback Javascript. Therefore it thinks that the LinkButtons are nested within a control that does not exist. And so the events aren't fired of course.

Once I removed the $ signs it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put this piece of code in the Page_Load and see. It's generally advised not to access controls in this Page_Init as there is no guarantee of the controls been created at this stage.

I'm no VB guy but i put this into the codebehind of the default.aspx and it works fine.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
            button.Text = "test";
            Form.Controls.Add(button);
        }

        void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. By the way, I have mostly read that it is best to initialize dynamic controls in the Page_Init method, so they will be available for postbacks. That's the reason I put them there. Would it be better to keep them in Page_Load?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example, you may want to have a look at. Oh BTW, I did the same inside the Page_Init and it works fine as well. So I suspect error might be in your foreach logic.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll take a closer look when I get to work on tuesday. I suspect that something in the hierarchy of the controls is wrong, since the example you posted was working ok and I am not doing anything completely different...